How to infer the return type base of a union type parameters
I have an Mapped Type, and want to implement a function which receive params as the key of MappedType, return the MappedType of key, however the code occurs an error.
type MappedType = {
  a: {
    a: string;
  };
  b: {
    b: number;
  }
};

function getValue<T extends keyof MappedType>(key: T): MappedType[T] | undefined {
  if (key === 'a') {
    // here get error
    // Type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MappedType[T]'.
    //   Type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; } & { b: number; }'.
    //    Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: string; }' but required in type '{ b: number; }'.
    return {
       a: '2'
    };
  }
  return;
}

how to infer the type successfully?

The error you're encountering happens because TypeScript can't determine that the return type inside the if block is specific to the key a.

To resolve this, you need to ensure TypeScript narrows down the type properly within the if block. This can be achieved by using a type assertion.

return { a: '2' } as MappedType['a'];

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use of the phrase "mapped type" is distracting, because it means something specific in TypeScript, and you're not using a mapped type anywhere in the question. Please consider changing the name to something more neutral (maybe Mapping or something?) so that people can more easily focus on your question.

(see prev comment.) Your problem is ms/TS#33014. Until that is implemented, you need to abandon either generics or control-flow analysis. I'd recommend abandoning control flow analysis and changing it to the version in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz seems what i need, but i'll examine tomorrow. you could write a question at least an an upvote guaranteed

Clarify the error context and expected behavior. Provide more details on the error and what you want to achieve.
